# putting a new line in the code below

Tags: php

```
$link = '1. <a href="http://example.com/landing_page2?id=' .$id. '"><img src="http://example.com/admin/img/example_Logo.jpg?id=' .$id. '"></a>


2. <iframe frameborder="0" width="270" height="270" src="http://www.example.com/partnerwidget/pid.php?id=' .$id. '"></iframe>' ;
```

i need to put a new line between these two links. I tried:

```
<?php
echo "\n";
?>
```

But it didn't work

Your help would be very much appreciable...

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP new line break](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3206531/php-new-line-break)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pulling out the big guns with [regex](/questions/tagged/regex):

```
$id = 3;
$link = '1. <a href="http://example.com/landing_page2?id=' .$id. '"><img src="http://example.com/admin/img/example_Logo.jpg?id=' .$id. '"></a>


2. <iframe frameborder="0" width="270" height="270" src="http://www.example.com/partnerwidget/pid.php?id=' .$id. '"></iframe>' ;

$link = preg_replace('#(\r\n?|\n)+#', '<br>$1', $link);
echo $link;
```

This will replace multiple lines with `<br>` + newline.
If you want a simpler solution, there is [`nl2br()`](http://php.net/nl2br), note that this will replace *every* newline with `<br>`.

```
$link = nl2br($link, false);
echo $link;
```

Comment: @FadilKausmally I tested it and it works, [here](http://ideone.com/mpyesC)'s an online demo.

Comment: @FadilKausmally may god bless you :-) Ah and next time please use `example.com` instead of `xxxx.com` I got a weird site ...

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
<?php
echo "<br />\n";
?>
```

This will put a new line for your source code, and also in your html view inside the browser.

Answer (score 1):

For this kind of work you need to do:

```
$link = <<<EOF
1. <a href="http://example.com/landing_page2?id={$id}"><img src="http://example.com/admin/img/XXXXX_Logo.jpg?id={$id}"></a>


2. <iframe frameborder="0" width="270" height="270" src="http://www.example.com/partnerwidget/pid.php?id={$id}"></iframe>
EOF;
```

This is used to assign the HTML exactly as is to a variable.

**There can be no space after the `<<<EOF` and there can be no space before or after the `EOF;`**

[Reference](http://forums.devshed.com/php-development-5/what-does-eof-mean-130815.html).