# How to add more space between paragraphs in php?

Tags: php, email

I created a contact form which on the part where it defines what will be received on the email there is:

```
 $message = ''; 
   // Set Message 
   $message .= "Email enviado por: " . $name . "\r\n"; 
   $message .= "Email: " . $email . "\r\n"; 
   $message .= "Mensagem:"; 
   $message .= $contact_message;
```

and the email received has no space between paragraphs:

My question is: How can I add more space between lines and including separate the name from email from message with a blank line?

Thank you

(transposed from stachechxange -- not duplicated)

Comment: use <br> tag while sending email it should go as html

Comment: Please see full code in http://codeshare.io/wfD5j

Comment: <br> does absolutely nothing...

Comment: OK added  $message .= "" "\r\n"; to create a new empty line and a break however but it gives an error of unexpected '"\r\n"' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING)

How can be done? Many thanks



Suggest found on:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3206531/php-new-line-break-in-emails/32459607

Comment: solved with $message .= "" . "\r\n"; (the dot to concatenate) 

Thanks @nisse-engström