# Laravel - How add break line in mail salutation?

Tags: laravel, laravel-mail

I do not want to create a new markdown file, only to include a line break in salutation "without a paragraph".

I tested everything:

```
->salutation("Atenciosamente,\n\n{$app}")
->salutation("{!! 'Atenciosamente,<br>' !!}{$app}")
->salutation(nl2br(e('Atenciosamente, <br>')). "{$app}")
...
```

**The simplest solution:**

To have a line break without a paragraph, you will need to use two trailing spaces with one enter.

[image]

Comment: Markdown line breaks are usually two spaces after the end of the sentence, try that :)

Comment: @MarinaMosti Your comment saved me. It worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 24):

To break line in MailMessage or add any html, use this code:

```
use Illuminate\Support\HtmlString;
```

...

```
return (new MailMessage)
->line(new HtmlString("Atenciosamente,<br><br>{$app}"));
```

Comment: Very nice answer! Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

This just worked for me

```php
...
->salutation("\r\n\r\n Regards,  \r\n Support.");
```

You can view a good [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3206531/php-new-line-break-in-emails) here.

Comment: this solution only works when used inside salutation and does not work in any other cases like greetings,line etc.  just for the info

Comment: Thanks! Lexx YungCarter...
This is working for me for now